# PDO select from multiple identical tables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to fetch datas from multiple identical tables (three and even more), they got the same columns names (but different datas in the rows).

So, I want to fetch with loops all the tables as if it was one query (one loop), not three.

I do not want to triple the number of columns when fetching the array. I want all the tables to use the same columns names. The datas of the tables will be stacked one over the other in the array, not one next to the other, tripling the number of columns in the array. But, once they get stacked one over the other, the "ORDER BY" filter will "blend" the tables : the "ORDER BY" will act on all the tables at once (like if it was only one table), not on all the tables individually.

My query for 1 table looks like this :

```
$pdo = "SELECT * FROM " .$table1 ." ORDER BY price LIMIT " 
       .$current_page_offset .", " .$items_per_pages;
```

So...I want to fetch the three tables like if I was fetching only one.

*also want to keep my limit and "ORDER BY" even more filters working. I do not want a triple-limit showing three times the number of items i want on my page...

Is there a way to do that ?

*EDIT : I changed my description of "blended" at 3rd paragraph. sorry for (maybe) my bad English.

Comment: "blended"? you need to get more specific. provide example data.

Comment: The way I understand it, he wants to append the resultset of one table to the resultset of the previous, identical tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/union.html):

> `UNION` is used to combine the result from multiple `SELECT` statements into a single result set.

Therefore, if your table names are in an array called `$tables`:

```
mb_regex_encoding($charset); // character set of database connection
foreach ($tables as $table) {
  $table = '`'.mb_ereg_replace('`','``',$table).'`';
  $sql[] = "(
    SELECT   *
    FROM     $table
    ORDER BY price
    LIMIT    $current_page_offset, $items_per_pages
  )";
}
$sql = implode(' UNION ALL ', $sql);
```

However it sounds as though your schema should be normalised, such that you don't have such "identical" tables: instead have a single table with an additional column to indicate whatever distinguishes each.

Comment: Should I put the ORDER BY at the complete end ? if I put it like you did, it sounds like it will order each tables individually before the union... ?

Comment: @Che: It depends what you're trying to achieve.  If the `LIMIT` must be taken over each individual table, then presumably the order of each select is important?  In which case, the `ORDER BY` clauses must go where I have put them (although one can also add a further `ORDER BY` to the end of the final `$sql` if the aggregated results must also be ordered).  However, I would again stress that you should almost certainly change your schema.