# PDO Query - Returning rows from multiple identical tables

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have a PDO Query which I am requesting the data of 5 identical tables from, I have tried a few ways of doing it, but can't seem to get any data back, the results just return empty.

```
SELECT * FROM
foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4, foo5
WHERE (
    foo1.id OR foo2.id OR foo3.id OR foo4.id OR foo5.id
)
= ?
```

Am I missing something here?
I found this question here [PDO select from multiple identical tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811492/pdo-select-from-multiple-identical-tables) but it didn't work for me either, there are definitely rows with the matching ID.

Comment: Because your conditions are FALSE. If you do not agree, just selected them in to select statement. Just use UNION ALL with where clause there.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean? It should return any rows that the ID matches on? Could you provide an example as an answer please?

Comment: I mean something like this for debug `select foo1.id, foo2.id as id2, foo3.id as id3 from foo1, foo2, foo3` without where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to query each table individually, then `UNION ALL` the result:

```
SELECT *
  FROM foo1
  WHERE foo1.id = ?
UNION ALL
SELECT *
  FROM foo2
  WHERE foo2.id = ?
UNION ALL
...
```

This is essentially what [PDO select from multiple identical tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811492/pdo-select-from-multiple-identical-tables) is saying. However, as with the other question, you should really stop and think about why you need to have five separate identical tables.

Comment: Thanks I understand that a lot more now, I'm going to give it a try and it may seem bad practice, but it's to store different types of values in a content management system, by having the multiple tables it overall allows me to save space by having a value column that is of type INT, TEXT etc